# Переносимость и безопасность

Tags: java

Если задачи переносимости и безопасности оказались актуальными
то зачем для их решения нужно было создавать новый язык программирования
вроде Java. Не проще ли было адаптировать для этой цели уже существующий
язык например С++? Можно ли создать компилятор
С++, который генерировал бы байт-код?

Comment: Никаких проблем в этом нет, по этой причине существует огромное количество языков программирования, как Python, Go, Scala, Kotlin, C и т.д. Просто язык Java разрабатывался, чтобы разработчик не думал о переносимости. Да, такой компилятор создать можно. Еще одна важная фишка Java + JVM - это java jit compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создание компилятора С++, который вместо исполняемого кода генерировал
бы байт-код, вполне возможно, но язык С++ обладает рядом свойств,
препятствующих его использованию для разработки интернет-приложений.
Самым важным из них является поддержка указателей. Указатель содержит
адрес некоторого объекта, находящегося в памяти. С помощью указателей
можно обращаться к ресурсам за пределами программы, что создает бреши в
системе безопасности. В Java указатели не поддерживаются, а следовательно, и
не возникает никаких осложнений, связанных с безопасностью.

Comment: Ого, быстро! Спасибо вам!

Comment: Указатели вообще не проблема, особенно для web. Никто же не запрещает вам не исполнять код, который вы получаете от клиента.